# PHP Laravel save() does not update record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, save

Looks like that is not the new question. But I have not found out any real solutioin.
Here is my code to expected it will work:

```
$update_pet=pets::where("pet_id",$pet['pet_id'])->get();
if($update_pet->count()>0){
    $update_pet=$update_pet->first();
    $update_pet->pet_breed_id=$pet_new['pet_breed_id'];
    $update_pet->save();
}
```

I am sure that $pet['pet_id'] and $pet_new['pet_breed_id'] has value.
And I am sure table pet_breeds in database has primary key as pet_id. The system can connect the database as I can get the pet_id and new pet_breed_id.
And I am sure I have overwrite table name and primaryKey value in model.

```
class pets extends Model
{
  protected $table="pets";
  protected $primaryKey="pet_id";
}
```

And it does not updated even.
Per now I am just directly using DB::update() to run the update query to solve the problem.
But I still want to know why it is happening? Or is it something wrong in the coding? Or the save function cannot used in update situation now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get an object instead of collection:

```
$pet = pets::find($pet['pet_id']);

if (!is_null($pet)) {
    $update_pet->pet_breed_id = $pet_new['pet_breed_id'];
    $update_pet->save();
}
```

Also, make sure you're getting the right object by putting `dd($pet);` right after the first line of the code.

Comment: I have tested it, worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Why make things complicated?

```
pets::find($pet['pet_id'])->update(['pet_breed_id' => $pet_new['pet_breed_id']]);
```

Also either include this line:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

or this one:

```
protected $fillable = ['pet_breed_id'];
```

in your pets model class.

One last thing, you should start all your classes name with capital. And model names should not be a plural. So...

```
class Pet extends Model
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change get() to first() so it will only return one data.

```
$update_pet=pets::where("pet_id",$pet['pet_id'])->first();
if($update_pet->count()>0){
    $update_pet=$update_pet->first();
    $update_pet->pet_breed_id=$pet_new['pet_breed_id'];
    $update_pet->save();
}e
```

Or if you need to update all the record that match with where condition, use foreach

```
$update_pet=pets::where("pet_id",$pet['pet_id'])->get();
foreach ($update_pet as $pet) {
    if($pet->count()>0){
        $pet=$update_pet->first();
        $pet->pet_breed_id=$pet_new['pet_breed_id'];
        $pet->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You using get method which gives you result as an array so don't do that using first method. If pet_id is your primary key.

```
$update_pet=pets::where("pet_id",$pet['pet_id'])->first();
if($update_pet->count()>0){
   $update_pet=$update_pet->first();
   $update_pet->pet_breed_id=$pet_new['pet_breed_id'];
   $update_pet->save();
}
```

and what is kind of stuff you are doing $update_pet->first() in line no 3 .